# Metal complexes and bonding of ligands

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I am currently learning about transition metal complexes, however I keep seeing complexes like $\ce{[Al(H2O)6}]^{3+}$ but aluminium isn't a transition metal. Is this a case that any metal can form a metal complex or is it just transition metals and a few others, if so which ones and why?

Comment: Second part is duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/why-do-copper-ii-complexes-contain-so-many-valence-electrons

Comment: Not only all "metals" but also most of "non metals" can form what can be called complexes, somewhat depending  on definition.

Comment: The nature of the bonding between metal ions and their ligands in complexes is probably of both the ionic type and the covalent type. In the complexes of the transition metals, it is clear that there is a large covalent contribution, in the form of dative covalent bonds. However, I believe that for ions such as $\ce {Mg^2+}$ or $\ce {Al^3+}$, the bonding may involve more of the ion-dipole interactions and less of electron donation via an orbital interaction.